# If I store image URL as string in Firebase realtime database , will the Usage Downloads size increase surprisingly?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

If I store image URL as string in Firebase real time database , will the Usage Downloads size increase surprisingly ? Usually String texts consume only few Kilo Bytes of storage , but using image URL as string is increasing the downloads to Mega Bytes (MB)

Comment: When saving a picture on firebase, its size decreases, but be careful.

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding the questions, or even whether you have a problem? If you have a problem with the way you currently store image URLs, please edit your question to show the [minimal, complete/standalone code and other information with which any of us can reproduce that problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Of course image file will be much bigger than plain text. Try taking a photo on your phone and check the file size. What's the problem?

Answer (score 1):

If you're worried about the size of the URLs that you store in the Realtime Database, then please note that there are some improvements that can be done. So to optimize the size of your URL, I have two options.

So the first solution would be to shorten the links using a Firebase Extension called [Shorten URLs](https://firebase.google.com/products/extensions/firebase-firestore-shorten-urls-bitly). After you shorten a URL, it will look similar to this:

> http:// bit.ly /someChars

The second solution requires saving two things in your database. It is not about shortening the URL, it's about storing fewer data. If you're using [Firebase Storage](https://firebase.google.com/products/storage) for storing your images, the URL of an image looks like this:

```
https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/project-id/o/images_folder
```

This can be considered a base URL. It includes the name of your project, the name of the folder where you store the images, the image name, and a token id that looks like this:

```
2277f575-8ff7-2211-8262-a28ef679d703
```

So you can store in your database only the name of the image and the token and then reconstruct the entire URL on the client. So in the example above the only things that you should store are:

```
Firebase-root
  |
  --- users
       |
       --- $uid
            |
            --- imageName: "wallpaper"
            |
            --- token: 2277f575-8ff7-2211-8262-a28ef679d703
            |
            --- //Other user details
```

These are the two solutions that can help you save and decrease the amount of data that you download.

Comment: Hey, Priyam. Can I help you with other information?